# Why the comment privilege needs 50 reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, comments

Why comments need 50 reputation? Everyone needs them to get more info from who asked the question in order to answer and get more reputation! I usually find questions that aren't very clear so I need to add a comment telling who asked the question to provide more info or the .blend file so I can answer the question and get more reputation. Because of this people with <50 reputation can hardly answer a question, and that will keep their reputation low, and that will keep the comment privilege locked, and the loop continues...

Comment: Related  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252133/50-reputation-points-to-make-comments. If you post an answer even without asking for details but still provide some potentially related and useful details the answer will have great chances to be upvoted.

Comment: It's mostly in place to prevent spam.